# Powershell Upper case replace

Tags: powershell

```
"qEwe" -replace 'E'
```

Result is **qw**, but i expected **qwe**. Why replace ignore case?

I thought, that pattern after operator is regexp, and **E** and **e** is a different chars.

Comment: `-replace` uses `i` and `g` modifiers. Its case insensitive

Comment: i and c. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, all string operators (including regular expression operators) are ***case-insensitive*** by default.

From the [`about_Comparison_Operators` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator):

> By default, the `-replace` operator is case-insensitive. To make it case sensitive, use `-creplace`. To make it explicitly case-insensitive, use `-ireplace`.

Using the case-sensitive variant (`-creplace`) produces the expected result:

```
PS ~> "qEwe" -creplace 'E'
qwe
```